# Plotting brownian motion matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

First of all, I just want to say that I'm not that used to using matlab, but I need for an assignment, I'm supposed to create a "brownian movement". My code is currently looking like this:

```
clf
hold on
prompt = 'Ge ett input';
size = input(prompt) ;
numParticles = input('Ange antal partiklar');
axis([-size size -size size]);
Part = [];
color = 'brkgmyco';
for i = drange(1:numParticles)
   Part = [Part [0;0]];
end
for i = drange(1:200)

    dxdy = randn(2,numParticles);
    k = Part
    Part = Part + dxdy;
```

My concern is how to print, I would even want like a small delay on every print, so you really can see what's happening for the assignment, is this possible to achieve from the code I've written for now or should anything be changed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can replace your first loop with `Part = zeros(2,numParticles);`

Comment: There's the [`pause`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some basic problems with your code, regardless of what you are trying to do:

1. You use `size` as a variable name. Doing so overrides MATLAB's function [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html).
2. The function [`zeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) creates an array initialized by zeros, no need for a loop for that.
3. Instead of calculating `randn` for 200 times in a loop, you can do it once, with `dxdy = randn(2,numParticles,200)` and then simply refer to `dxdy(:,:,i)` within the loop.
4. The same holds for summation. Instead of summing within a loop to get the cumulative sum, use [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) like `Part = cumsum(randn(2,numParticles,200),3);` and then refer to `Part(:,:,i)`, within the loop.

Now to your task. You said you want to know how to print, but I believe you want to *plot* because you use some commands like `axis`, `clf` and `hold`, that refer to graphic objects. However, you never really do plot anything.
The basic and general function for plotting in 2D is [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), but there are many other more specific functions. One of them is `scatter`, and it has a sister function [`gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html), that takes triples of `x`, `y` and `group`and plot each `(x(k),y(k))` colored by their `group(k)`.

This code plots the particles on an axes, and animate their movement:

```
prompt = 'Ge ett input';
scope = input(prompt) ;
numParticles = input('Ange antal partiklar');
N = 500;
Part = cumsum(randn(2,numParticles,N)*scope/100,3);
h = gscatter(Part(1,:,1),Part(2,:,1),1:numParticles);
axis([-scope scope -scope scope]);
legend off
for k = 2:N
    for p = 1:numParticles
        h(p).XData = Part(1,p,k);
        h(p).YData = Part(2,p,k);
    end
    drawnow
end
```

Is this what you look for?

Comment: sorry, just got home and started looking into it again, gonna try your code and see if I can understand it as well :)

Comment: Think I solved it with your help, well, you solved it, but I need code that I understand :), thanks a lot for the help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you wrote it again in a way you understand it's even better!

Comment: I'm doing another exercise for the matlab, I wonder if you can help me with that one as well... Im supposed to do a chessboard, I know how to generate a matrix corresponding of 1:s and 0:s, I wanna paint the 0:s white and the 1:s black, the matrix is a hilbert matrix if that says you anything

Comment: I don't understand what is the connection between chessboard and hilbert, but for ploting a matrix in different colors look at [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html), and for hilbert matrix look at [`hilb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hilb.html).