# Brownian motion with multiple molecules/particles [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, statistics

I want to model the Brownian motion with multiple molecules/particles and animate them. So far I have come up with this code solution but I am unable to get the desired result. Below is my code

```
N   =  500;  % number of samples
tau = .1;    % time interval in seconds
D   =  10;   % diffusion coefficient
NumMolecules  =  500;  % number of moelcues to be released
k  = sqrt(2*D*tau);   % scaling factor
dx = k * randn(N,NumMolecules);
dy = k * randn(N,NumMolecules);
x  = cumsum(dx);
y  = cumsum(dy);
h  = gscatter(x(1,:),y(1,:),1:NumMolecules,'b');
for k = 2:N
    for p = 1:NumMolecules
        h(p).XData = x(k,p);
        h(p).YData = x(k,p);
    end
    drawnow limitrate
end
drawnow
```

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to get the desired results?

**Edit**

Desired result: To animate the motion of the molecules using ‘drawnow’ function

Comment: *the desired result*. Well, it completely depends what you desire! If you desire the code to output cupcakes, we cannot help. If your desire is something else, then please tell us, as we might be able to help.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have added an Edit :)

Comment: Why does it not work? Your code looks very similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632393/plotting-brownian-motion-matlab), and that code works

Comment: @AnderBiguri I get a straight line. And in the link you sent the diffusion coefficient is not taken into consideration

Comment: The link I send plots random points and animates them, which is what you want. Ultimately, you just have a typo though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `h(p).YData = x(k,p);` change it to `h(p).YData = y(k,p);`

It's plotting the same numbers against each other right now, which is why you get a straight line.